# How to count the number of words and lines in a string that is separated by System.lineSeparator()?

Tags: java, separator

I have a class `Parser` that takes in `List<String> lines` as its field. I am trying to create the method `linecount()` and `wordcount()` to output the number of lines and words respectively.

This is what I have:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Parser{
  static List<String> lines;

  public static String parse(List<String> lines){
    return String.join(System.lineSeparator(), lines); 
  }

  public static int linecount(){
    String newString = String.join(System.lineSeparator(), lines); 
    return newString.split("[\r\n]").length;
  }

  public static int wordcount(){
    String[] newStringArr = String.split("[\r\n]");
    int counter = (String.split("[\r\n]")).length;
    for (String a : newStringArr){
      counter = counter + (a.length() - a.replaceAll(" ", "").length());
    return counter;
  }
}
```

Given my list of lines: `List lines = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"one", "two three", ""})`

if I call the method `Parser.parse(lines).linecount()` I should get an output of `3`, and the method `Parser.parse(lines).wordcount()` should also give me an output of `3`. However, I am getting an error. May I know how to resolve this?

These are the errors I'm getting:

> Error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method
>   split(java.lang.String) from the type java.lang.String
>
> Error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method
>   split(java.lang.String) from the type java.lang.String
>
> Error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method
>   split(java.lang.String) from the type java.lang.String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the `split()` of the *String* class is not *static*. Look closely at the signature of the method from the [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-).

> public String[] split(String regex)

As the compiler clearly complains, you cannot make a static reference to a non-static method.

Maybe you need this?

```
public static int wordcount(String myString) {
    String[] newStringArr = myString.split("[\r\n]");
    int counter = myString.split("[\r\n]").length;
    for (String a : newStringArr) {
        counter = counter + (a.length() - a.replaceAll(" ", "").length());
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Pass in a *String* argument to `wordCount()` and then perform the *split* operation on it. Also, you were missing a closing bracket.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
private static String array;

public static void parse(List<String> lines){
    array = String.join(System.lineSeparator(), lines); 
}

public static int lines(){
    return (array.split("[\r\n]")).length;
}

public static int words() {
    String[] newStringArr = array.split("[\r\n]");
    int counter = (array.split("[\r\n]")).length;
    for (String a : newStringArr){
      counter = counter + (a.length() - a.replaceAll(" ", "").length());
    }
    return counter;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> lines = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"one", "two three", ""});
    LineCounter.parse(lines);
    System.out.println(LineCounter.lines());
    System.out.println(LineCounter.words());
}
```

Comment: Hi, this works as well, but is there a way to do it without the LineCounter function and just purely through linecount() and wordcount() methods? :)

Answer (score 0):

You aren't splitting on anything right now. Here you are trying to statically call split on the String class. You need to split on an instance of a string. All of your methods are static, so if you want them to split something or count the words you need to pass that value in.

```
  public static int linecount(){
    return (String.split("[\r\n]")).length;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you splitting here..? You do realize that you cant't write `String.split(..)` . you need to call split on the `object ( string )` to split it.
why not you try some thing like:

```
public static int getWordCount(String lines){
return lines.split(" |\n").length;//based on word separator <space>  and \n

}

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String nChars = "ABCDEF 12\nBLue";
        System.out.println(getWordCount(nChars));
    }
```